# sometimes click of hyperlink in email to ASP.NET web app results in unexpected 'ghost' Page_Load() event 13 seconds after first event

Tags: c#, asp.net, windows, iis

Sometimes when a user clicks a hyperlink in email from me, the hyperlink is processed by ASP.NET twice instead of once.

1. My .NET backend app sends an email to a user; email contains a hyperlink to my ASP.NET web site.
2. Hyperlink's URL contains a unique number.
3. When user clicks hyperlink, ASP.NET calls Page_Load() to process it, reads unique number from URL, and if my Session("unique") variable is not already set to unique number, then ASP.NET does some processing.

Normally, this process works every time.
But sometimes Page_Load() is unexpectedly called a 2nd time (13 seconds after 1st time), and the Session("unique") variable is now empty.  I'm surprised because I understood Session variables to last a lot longer than 13 seconds.

Backend .NET and ASP.NET on Visual Studio 2017 Pro.
Server for backend and ASP.NET is Azure VM Windows Server 2012.

***NEWS***
HERE IS THE PROBLEM I BELIEVE.............
2nd ghost hyperlink event has different IP...

Events...
1. I clicked hyperlink at my Verizon iPhone 
2. 1st hyperlink from Verizon IP goes to my web OK
3. 14 seconds later, 2nd hyperlink identical to first, but from MICROSOFT IP (40.107.238.44 and others) goes to my web, and is new session due to different IP, and so erroneously also processed.

Workaround is to ignore web event if same URL from different IP.

So, why does hyperlink from email on my iPhone generate a duplicate hyperlink from microsoft IP?  The email with the hyperlink was generated by my .NET windows app on my Azure Windows Server 2012 IIS  VM.  The hyperlink's URL is my ASP.NET app on same Azure Windows Server 2012 IIS VM.

Comment: Are you using InProc state management? If so maybe you can try State Server.

Comment: If the request originated from the same user you would expect the session to work so its likely not originating from them, take a look in the IIS logs at the user-agent of the second request, perhaps its say Gmail deciding to examine the link for some reason.

Comment: I assume I'm using inProc, since I didn't change it.

Comment: Alex K. That's not it.  I open the email and click hyperlink. My web receives URL from hyperlink and processes ok.  But then after about 13 seconds it receives erroneous URL from hyperlink, identical to first.  Normally I filter this, in case user did backspace or refresh, and store the latest URL sequence # in a session variable.  But mysteriously to me this session variable is reset.  Maybe hardkoded State Server is worth a try.

Comment: *NEWS* Problem seems to be that ghost 2nd hyperlink URL event is from a different IP from MICROSOFT !!  Gaahh!  (see details just added above).  So, workaround I'll try is to ignore hyperlink from different IP.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I modified my ASP.NET web app to check for non-authentic hyperlink hits on my web, ie. same URL as previous authentic event to my web, but a different IP.

Question remains:  Why does Microsoft hit my web with non-authentic hyperlink hits?